# Change delimiter in a DB2 script

Tags: sql, docker, db2, dbeaver

I have setup DB2 v11.5.5.1 in a Docker container and accessed it via DBeaver.

I want to run a script with a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement on DB2 database.

But it returns `SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "E IF EXISTS TEMP_IDS"`.

The sample script I tried is here.

```sql
--#SET DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name ()
BEGIN
    -- some statements;
END$$
```

How can I solve this delimiter issue in DB2 script? I think the issue with changing the delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are trying to use a Db2 CLP (command line processor) feature inside DBEaver, i.e you are trying to use `--#SET TERMINATOR...`.

This feature `--#SET TERMINATOR` is available if you execute your script with the Db2 clp  (i.e. on MS-Windows that is db2.exe,  and on linux/unix the `db2` command in the shell).

For Dbeaver, a jdbc application, there is a different method to configure the alternative statement terminator / delimiter. Use the properties settings to find this option and choose a valid character in that GUI. Then retry.

For example, in Dbeaver Community Edition version 2021.04, use:

```
File > Properties > Editors > SQL Exitor > SQL Processing: "Statements Delimiter"
```

Comment: In addition to changing `Statements delimiter` to a valid character I had to turn on `Ignore native delimiter`. Now it's working.