# Unexpected Token was found

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have this sample code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION REVERSE(INSTR VARCHAR(4000))
     RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
     DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION CONTAINS SQL
     BEGIN ATOMIC
     DECLARE REVSTR, RESTSTR VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT '';
     DECLARE LEN INT;
     IF INSTR IS NULL THEN
     RETURN NULL;
     END IF;
     SET (RESTSTR, LEN) = (INSTR, LENGTH(INSTR));
     WHILE LEN > 0 DO
     SET (REVSTR, RESTSTR, LEN) 
       = (SUBSTR(RESTSTR, 1, 1) CONCAT REVSTR, 
       SUBSTR(RESTSTR, 2, LEN - 1),
       LEN - 1);
     END WHILE;
     RETURN REVSTR;
   END
```

That IBM provides from this URL:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/ko/db2/9.7?topic=statements-create-function-sql-scalar-table-row

Unfortunately, I get these errors when I try to run it:

[image: Screenshot of db2 errors]

What I am I doing wrong?

I am using DB2 LUW 9.7

I tried IBM's sample code because I was having a hard time writing a function with my own code and tried all kinds of combinations of moving the semicolons.

EDIT 1:
I added:

```
--#SET DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION REVERSE(INSTR VARCHAR(4000))
...
END$$
```

And still got a bunch for syntax errors.

Comment: If you use "compound sql" as a function body, you must use some statement termination character (say, `@`) different from `;` and put it at the end of the whole statement (after the final `END` clause). Every tool must have a place, where such a statement termination character is specified. Find this place and put this statement terminator there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change delimiter in a DB2 script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67396368/change-delimiter-in-a-db2-script)

Comment: Your edited example with `--#SET TERMINATOR` works with Db2 Command Line Processor (DB2 CLP) **only**. And this statement really works being run from Db2 CLP. But you run this statement not from DB2 CLP, but from some another GUI tool, which is not affected by this instruction. Once again, have you found the corresponding place in this tool (which one?), where custom statement termination character(s) can be specified?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I will look but is there a way to write functions such they can be run from command and from a third party tool?  Seems kinda weird that there is not a universal way create a function.

Comment: Sure. Absolutely the same script of sql statements can be run from whatever tool. Db2 CLP has an ability to use different statement separator (using a command option) without this `--SET TERMINATOR` instruction.